# ImageView Keeps Laying On Side

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, rotation

Here is my issue.  My app starts out in Landscape mode, and looks like this

[image]

I have a couple of images for the door that look like:

[image]

[image]

In the AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, I add the following code, with the intent to lay the two door images in the same place as the launch image, and then animate to show the door opening.

```
{
 myImageWalk = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(272,0, 286, 748)];
        myImageWalk.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"leftdoorlandscape.png"];
        [window addSubview:myImageWalk];
        [window bringSubviewToFront:myImageWalk];
        myImageWalk2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(512,0, 286, 748)];
        myImageWalk2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rightdoorlandscape.png"];
        [window addSubview:myImageWalk2];
        [window bringSubviewToFront:myImageWalk2];
        [self doAnimate:CGRectMake(-286, 20, self.myImageWalk.frame.size.width, self.myImageWalk.frame.size.height)];
        [self doAnimate1:CGRectMake(748, 20, self.myImageWalk2.frame.size.width, self.myImageWalk2.frame.size.height)];
}
```

The only problem is that the result is:

[image]

How come when the image is straight up and down, it displays it on its side?

Comment: It can be added on rootviewcontroller rather than window right?

Comment: Well, the root view controller's view, but yeah, that seems like a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding on the window which wont handle the auto rotation, you need to add it on the rootViewController of the application. That should automatically handle the orientation as well.

Comment: I asked a stupid question.  Forgot to add the .view to the rootViewController